# 302 redirect of HTTPS request to HTTP - can encrypted content be exposed?

Tags: security, http, ssl, https

## Situation

HTTPS request to ***https***://www.example.com/ is redirected (302) to fake HTTP URL ***http***://www.example.com/ by the man in the middle (e.g. compromised proxy server).

I am assuming http client will use almost identical request, with all the headers and content, and send it to the new URL. Maybe client is smart enough to avoid it - I haven't tested this myself. Before I do so, maybe someone with the knowledge could answer this.

## Question

Is it possible to eavesdrop on headers and content during the call to the fake HTTP redirect URL?

Comment: If the attacker can tamper with the HTTPS request's response, couldn't they send a malicious page to steal all of `https://www.example.com`'s data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To have this kind of redirect you must have compromised the connection or session already, e.g. by mounting a man-in-the-middle attack with a faked certificate (which the client explicitly need to accept), by owning an intercepting proxy (usually a firewall) or by using an cross-site-request or similar attack against the site to create a redirect inside the browser.

If any of this is true the whole security is compromised and data can be extracted by a variety of methods, not only redirects.